# Shapley value vs ridge regression

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients, ridge-regression, shapley-value

My goal is to get the feature importance for multiple regression. I have a data set with some multicollinearity. I found two methods to solve this problem.

The first one is the Shapley value. Shapley value computes the regression using all possible combinations of predictors and computes the R$^2$ for each model. Then for each predictor, the average improvement will be calculated that is created when adding that variable to a model.

As an example, I use the Boston data set (I found this result on different data sets).

```
library(relaimpo)
library(MASS)
data(Boston)

mod_lm = lm(medv ~ ., data = Boston)

calc.relimp(mod_lm, type = c("lmg"))
```

The relative importance is scaled to 100%. In the case, Islat is ~5.5 times as important as tax (I just show the relative importance but not the whole output).

```
    Relative importance metrics: 

               lmg
crim    0.03669197
zn      0.03349910
indus   0.05101231
chas    0.02139033
nox     0.04511571
rm      0.25259867
age     0.02975151
dis     0.04087946
rad     0.03190385
tax     0.04967225
ptratio 0.10602348
black   0.03093651
lstat   0.27052485
```

Ridge regression adds a penalty to all beta coefficients. The size of the penalty is dependent on the RMSE in the cross-validation or bootstrap. I standardize the data to get the relative importance.

```
library(caret) 

Boston_scaled = scale(Boston)

fit = train(medv~., data = Boston_scaled, 
            method = "glmnet", 
            preProcess = NULL, 
            tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 0, lambda = seq(0,1, by = 0.1)))
                   

coef(fit$finalModel, fit$bestTune$lambda)
```

In this case, Islat is only 3.5 times as important as tax.

```
14 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                                    1
(Intercept) -0.0000000000000006334209
crim        -0.0819019359606095592730
zn           0.0828741063806194971919
indus       -0.0283478772157603683968
chas         0.0800825186065121513712
nox         -0.1501007822559678184238
rm           0.3064458129978267497684
age         -0.0114206187124149035478
dis         -0.2561703730728009387185
rad          0.1455422731561680227408
tax         -0.1053881725850110001597
ptratio     -0.2012584716226800130023
black        0.0900702979932691133458
lstat       -0.3668119207994711694631
```

Since both metrics are standardized I should get similar results. Can someone explain the difference in the results?

Comment: You're comparing ridge regression coefficients to shapley values from a random forest?  These measure quite different things, so there's no reason they should tell the same story.

Comment: No, Shapely values were calculated based on the OLS (see `mod_lm`) and the standardized Betacoeficients based on ridge regression. Both are the same methods besides the shrinking parameter in the ridge regression.

Comment: It is Shapley, and not Shapely. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Shapley values care computed based on game-theoretic basis, whilst the ridge regression is not. Perhaps this is the reason ..

Comment: @sdgaw erzswer: Yes, I know both have two different theoretical backgrounds. I want to understand why the methods have different results and which of both methods is wrong. I read about both methods but I don´t get it. Maby there is an error in the calculation. However, the feature importance is calculated based on the betacoeficients. So the results should be similar. Maby it´s because the standardized betas are between - 1 and 1 and not between 1 and 0.

Comment: I think the following are possible reasons: Scaling. As you say, [-1,1] != [0,1], thus the ratios between importances are naturally different. The $k$ in the ridge regression is also a factor when importances are computed. Have you tried varying that? Have you considered e.g., myopic mutual information? This could shed some light.

Comment: "Which of both methods is wrong". There's no fundamental concept of "correct" here. No one agrees on what something we call "feature importance" should measure, and people barely agree on what properties such a measure should have. It's a coincidence that both of these methodologies are labeled a "feature importance", they simply measure different things.

Comment: @ Matthew Drury: "Feature Importance" means which predictors drives the target variable the most. The results of different measures could be different because they measure on different scales, measure something different or because they are biased. I want to understand why they are different.

Comment: I agree with @MatthewDrury, feature importance != feature ranking.

Comment: @Banjo From that perspective, they just measure something different. I would like to note though, that the definition that you offer of "feature importance", just passes the responsibility of precision to defining what you mean by "drive the target variable", which is also an undefined term / phrase. That's just not rigorous enough to define a real concept in statistics or machine learning.

Comment: @Matthew Drury Yes, that's right and thanks for your patience. However, Shaply Value refers to the amount of explained variance by each predictor (R2) while the Ridge Regression betas refer to the amount of variation of the target variable, caused by each predictor. Both are different measures but they are similar (i.e. the more variable changes the predictor the more variance will be explained!?). So, my intuition was, that they contain similar information regarding the impact on the target variable.

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons why the two sets of values you computed are not the same:

#### $R_2$ contributions are not partial correlation or regression coefficients

The package you use to compute Shapley values computes contribution to the $R^2$. This is a value between 0 and 1. Ridge regression coefficients on standardized data are partial correlations and can take any value between -1 and 1. Accounting for this takes away a lot (but surely not all) of the discrepancies:

```
ridge_coefs <- coef(fit$finalModel, fit$bestTune$lambda)
shapley_vals <- calc.relimp(mod_lm, type = c("lmg"))$lmg
cor(ridge_coefs[-1], shapley_vals, method = "spearman")
[1] -0.4505495
cor(abs(ridge_coefs[-1]), shapley_vals, method = "spearman")
[1] 0.6703297
```

Perhaps you also want to take the square root of the Shapley, but for the Spearman correlation this will not matter.

#### Computation of Shapley values differs from that of partial correlations

Shapley values are not partial correlations. The Shapley value gives a weighted average of the increases in $R^2$ when a given predictor is added to all possible sets of predictors excluding that predictor (as computed by the package you use, note there are many ways to compute Shapley values, see e.g., [Chen et al., 2022: Algorithms to estimate Shapley value feature attributions](https://arxiv.org/abs/2207.07605)). This procedure is different than the (penalized) partial regression coefficients (partial correlations in your case) computed in a ridge regression, which can be computed as follows once the value of $\lambda$ has been chosen:

$$\hat{\beta} = (X^\top X + \lambda I)^{-1}X^\top y$$

#### Regularization

The ridge coefficients are shrunken towards 0, the Shapley values you computed are not.